# Why do I get a timeout when uploading files larger than 100KB?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, file-upload, timeoutexception

I have a web site on IIS7. I can upload a maximum of 100KB, but if I try any files larger than 100K then I get a timeout error.

I have added following setting to my `web.config` file but I am getting the same error:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000"></requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Is this an ASP or ASP.NET site? Do you have console/RDP admin access to the server?

Comment: site is asp.net and I have no access to server with console or RDP :(

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check your `<httpRuntime>` element in the web.config to ensure that it isn't limiting your request size there.

Comment: thanks your answer, but there is no limit:   httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096"

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the [`HttpServerUtility.ScriptTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout.aspx) property. You can do this in your script:

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 300; // Set timeout to 300 seconds
```

Or you can configure in your `web.config` in:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
       executionTimeout = "300"
    />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For more info see:

> [httpRuntime Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx)